# Selecting all elements whose parents don't have a certain class (using '.not()')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-traversal

I am trying to select all elements with the class `.select` which are nested somewhere in the DOM-tree.
The only restriction is, they're not allowed to have any parents with the class `.forbidden`.

So it would not find any elements in following tree part:

```
<div>
    <div class="forbidden">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="select">Some Content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But would find 1 element in here:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="select">Some Content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this selection by using the `.not()` function?
Something like this:    `$('.select').not($(this).parents().hasClass('.forbidden'));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to check for parent elements, and `closest()` stops at the first element found with that class, and if the selector has length, ie. contains elements, there is an element somewhere up the DOM tree with that class.

```
$('.select').filter(function(){
     return !$(this).closest('.forbidden').length;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would not use `:not`.

But I would use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
$('.select').filter(function(){return !$(this).parents().is('.forbidden')});
```

Note that [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns true if at least one element of the set (here the parents) matches the selector.

Comment: I like this solution better, as it lets you decide how many levels you check upwards the DOM tree; you can use `parents()`, `parentsUntil()` or just `parent()` which just checks one level up.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.select').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.forbidden').length == 0;
});
```